# Как в PopupMenu уменьшить высоту пунктов и шрифт текста в них?

Tags: java, android

Пробовал через задание стиля так:

```
PopupMenu m3;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
   m3 = new PopupMenu(this, view, Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK, 0, R.style.PopupMenuStyle);
}
else { 
   m3 = new PopupMenu(this, view); 
}
```

Стиль:

```
<style name="PopupMenuStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
<item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
<item name="android:height">16sp</item>
</style>
```

Не могу найти какое свойство отвечает за высоту каждого пункта и отступ с боков.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В теме для всего приложения попробуйте прописать следующий параметр. Но он повлияет не только на Popup

```
<item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">size_in_dp</item>
```

Шрифт задается так же в теме приложения через параметр

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
```

Comment: Это работает, но все таки нужно применить только к определенному Popup.

Comment: попробуйте этот item засунуть в свой стиль

Comment: пробовал, сразу становится все дефолтное.

Comment: значит этот параметр исключительно темы, а не стилей, можете написать свой кастомный PopupMenu :)

Comment: Да я бы рад, но как? Можете пример сделать?

Comment: пишете кастомный класс MyPopupMeny extends PopupMenu и там полная свобода действий. можете вообще полностью внешний вид переделать, но это как из пушки по воробьям.